How to know when to import a namespace when its not automatically imported
A few hours ago I was following this part of BasicMvvmSample of AvaloniaUI. I am using JetBrains Rider 2024.2 as my IDE and here is the code
using ReactiveUI;

namespace BasicMvvmSample.ViewModels;

public class ReactiveViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private string? _name;
    public string? Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value);
    }

    public string? Greeting => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) ? "Hello Welcome to avalonia" : $"Hello {Name}";

    public ReactiveViewModel()
    {
        this.WhenAnyValue(o => o.Name)
            // Error is here
            .Subscribe(o => this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Greeting)));
    }
}

I got stuck when the "o =>" in the Subscribe method showed an error saying The delegate type could not be inferred. This was happening because I didn't manually import the System namespace. After about 3 hours of tomfoolery, I wrote some code that automatically imported the System namespace after which I noticed that this was the problem itself. Here is a picture of the tooltip I got from JB Rider.
I was expecting to atleast be notified by the IDE of a missing namespace. My question is how do I get a better understanding of when to import a namespace in C#. I don't want to be wasting time on issues as trivial as this if it happens again.

Enabling implicit usings will probably help, but “how do I get a better understanding” is way too broad a question for stack overflow.

@Sweeper Oh alright. Thanks for notifying about implicit usings tho, I didn't know those existed in c#, that solves my concerns about the namespaces.
